# How to get number of element ref by id using javascript?

Tags: javascript

How to get number of element by id using javascript ?

http://jsfiddle.net/3AaAx/51/

normally, after load page , it's will alert `2` (length of element id `ele1`).

But why alert `undefined`

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="ele1" class="test" value="test"> 
<input type="text" id="ele1" class="test" value="test">    
<script>
$(function() {
//var xxx = document.getElementsByClassName('test');
var xxx = document.getElementById('ele1');    
var xxx;
alert(xxx.length);
});
</script>
```

Comment: What do you mean by ref? Also, if you're accessing an element by id, it's length will always be 1. You should use classes.

Comment: `var xxx = $('#ele1');`

Comment: `document.getElementById('ele1')` does not return an array so property length will be undefined

Comment: `xxx.value.length` perhaps?

Comment: @RobG - i want to get element length not value length.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Counting div elements based on id](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1693109/counting-div-elements-based-on-id)

Comment: Shorty said: Ids should be unique, use classes instead, than you can get your array with `getElementsByClassName()`

Comment: @robertdewo—perhaps then you should change the id to a name and use *getElementsByName*.

Answer (score 4):

[`getElementById()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.getElementById) returns just an element. A single element has no property `length`. (There may be exceptions, but in general ... Even if there is a `length` property it most likely does *not* refer to the amount of elements returned.)

You probably refer to the `getElementsBy...()` (note the `s`!) or [`querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document.querySelectorAll) functions, which return a [`NodeList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList), which has a `length` property.

Comment: Adding to this, `getElementsBy..()` will not work on ids but classes or element types.

Answer (score 0):

This is how you get the number of elements returned by `getElementById`:

```
var xxx = (document.getElementById('ele1') === null) ? 0 : 1;
```

`getElementById` returns `null` if no element matched the `id`. If the function does not return `null`, then one and only one element matches the criteria. See more [here](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_getelementbyid.asp).

Answer (score 0):

The line you commented off is right:

```
//var xxx = document.getElementsByClassName('test');
```

`getElementsByClassName` returns a collection of DOM elements, which does have a `length` property. Note in this method **Elements** is **plural form**. `length` indicates the amount of elements in the collection.

However you misunderstand `getElementById`. This method will only return a DOM element (or `null` if there isn't such element). Note in this method **Element** is **singular** form. A DOM element doesn't have a `length` property usually.

Another problem in your code, ID should be **unique** within a page. If you have two or more elements with the same ID, that's illegal markup. In such case you will get unexpected result.